# Google Cloud, Kubernetes and Volumes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCE and K8s and I'm trying to figure out my first deployment, but I get an error with my volumes:

`Failed to attach volume "pv0001" on node "xxxxx" with: GCE persistent disk not found: diskName="pd-disk-1" zone="europe-west1-b"
Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "xxx". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[registrator-claim0]`

This is my storage yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk: 
    fsType: ext4
    pdName: pd-disk-1
```

This is my Claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: registrator-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

This is my Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: consul
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        service: consul
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: consul
          image: eu.gcr.io/xxxx/consul
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8300
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 8400
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 8500
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 53
            protocol: UDP
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
          args:
            - -server
            - -bootstrap
            - -advertise=$(MY_POD_IP)

        - name: registrator
          args:
            - -internal
            - -ip=192.168.99.101
            - consul://localhost:8500
          image: eu.gcr.io/xxxx/registrator
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp/docker.sock
              name: registrator-claim0
      volumes:
        - name: registrator-claim0 
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: registrator-claim0
status: {}
```

What am I doing wrong? Figuring out K8s and GCE isn't that easy. These errors are not exactly helping. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've to create the actual storage before you define the PV, this can be done with sth like:

```
# make sure you're in the right zone
$ gcloud config set compute/europe-west1-b 

# create the disk
$ gcloud compute disks create --size 10GB pd-disk-1
```

Once thats available you can create the PV and the PVC

Comment: Thx a lot for the help!